# end of file VS bytes containing zero

Tags: 16.04, ram, system

I was just messing around with the system to learn how to extend swap memory. Then I came to know about `/dev/zero`. It is refered to as brother of `/dev/null`(I read it somewhere).

Then I ran `man zero`,

The discription says,

```
       Reads  from /dev/null always return end of file (i.e., read(2) returns 0), whereas reads from /dev/zero always return bytes contain‐
   ing zero ('\0' characters).
```

What is the difference between this end of file and bytes containing zero? Aren't they same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're confusing two usages of the phrase "zero bytes"

- a count (zero) of bytes (/dev/null)
- a (non-zero) count of bytes whose *value* is zero (/dev/zero)

The difference is probably best illustrated with an example:

Reading from `/dev/zero`

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8 count=1 | od
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
0000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
8 bytes copied, 0.000207568 s, 38.5 kB/s0000010
```

returns a stream of bytes whose ASCII value is zero (*"null bytes"*); whereas attempting to read from `/dev/null`

```
$ dd if=/dev/null bs=8 count=1 | od
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0000000
0 bytes copied, 0.000168108 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

returns 0 bytes.

Comment: actually when you make a file with `dd` using `/dev/null`, the size of file is 0. But if you make it using `/dev/zero`, its size is the size we specify, what is the difference ? Can we make a file with `/dev/null` and then use it as swap memory ? I think not, but why is that ? Upoted your answer but not verified yet.